# How fixed are the ICC profile in core app?

Tags: app

Will ICC profiles here always be a core part of Craft app?
`/craft/app/vendor/pixelandtonic/imagine/lib/Imagine/resources/Adobe/CMYK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm following 100%, but they're part of the [Imagine library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/tree/develop/src/resources/Adobe/CMYK) so as long as Craft is using that library, they will be included in Craft.